# What NRF24L01 module is this?

Tags: nrf24l01+, uart, wireless, rf

I received my NRF24L01 Module today but I'm having a hard time finding any resources about this particular combination of modules!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiwyj.jpg

I tried searching up the v200 1812A but no results...You would think the seller would have some documentation on his page but nothing.

Does anyone know what I'm dealing with here?

Thank you!

Comment: What numbers are on the chips?

Comment: @Majenko Both the modules display the same V200 1812A, the only slight variation is that one says WSCOM and the other WSUSB

Comment: I asked what is on the CHIPS not on the MODULE.

Comment: Excuse me, the WSCOM module has a chip with the markings (ST MICROELECTRONICS) 78754 32F03DF4O6 PHL B17 A

Comment: That sounds like an STM32F0 ARM M0 chip?

Comment: I highly doubt it. You can see the sheer difference in size and pins on the chip

Comment: The actual number is not what you read (it can be hard to distinguish some letters / numbers), but is [32F030F406](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f030f4.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

They are transparent bridge modules that are designed specifically to work together. It's intended to be kind of like a wireless UART.

[This AliExpress Seller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32981140607.html) details how to use them.

You need one UART and one USB module. You plug the UART module into the USB module and plug the USB module into your computer. After about 10 seconds the modules are paired together.

You then separate them, and you can connect the UART module to your Arduino or other board.

Now you have a wireless UART between your computer and your Arduino.

Alternatively, since they have an STM32F0 chip controlling them you could hack them to do other things using `stm32duino`.

Comment: Ah thanks! Is an Arduino library available to work with it? That's all whats left what's keeping me to work on it!

Comment: To use it as is there's nothing to "use". You just plug it in (once it's paired) like you would an FT232 cable.

Comment: So wait, I can't connect this to my arduino? I thought that I would've been able to communicate between my pc and my arduino... Even that seller page never mentioned the usage of an Arduino

Comment: Once paired you connect the UART portion to the Arduno. Like you'd connect the TTL UART side of an FT232 cable to the Arduino.

Comment: Alright, 1 last question. Since the breakout of the UART module differs alot from the "standard" NRF24l01 module, how should I connect the RXD and TXD part of the WSCOM module to my arduino? I dont suppose I can just hook it up to my Arduino Micro's RX and TX?

Comment: If you're not using them for the USB interface then yes, you can. Or to any other pins and use SoftwareSerial. It's. Just. Serial.